# ActiveMQ: enable Web Console in a CXF Project

Tags: java, maven, activemq-classic, wildfly-8, hawtio

i'm trying to figure out how to startup a web console for my Apache CXF-Maven project.

It's quite messy cause it's not a standard project, i'm actually implementing the wsn\services from the cxf-master SVN or GITHUB developed by the Apache CXF Team.

I've read that there's also the hawtio console, but is even more complicated...

I need to some info, some help, to point me to the right direction.
I'm using wildfly 8.2.0 Final.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the question could be a bit more clear, but I will assume you have a maven based web application that embeds an ActiveMQ broker. You then want to enable the ActiveMQ web console for that broker. Correct?

First, the Web Console is a stand alone web application that you can deploy in whatever container you want, like Wildfly. You simply have to get the .war (by building activemq-web-console from source or [grabbing the .war from maven repo](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/activemq/activemq-web-console/5.11.1/activemq-web-console-5.11.1.war)). Then you need to make that .war point out your ActiveMQ broker using JMS and JMX by setting a few system properties.

Like this (adjust to your values):

```
-Dwebconsole.type=properties
-Dwebconsole.jms.url=tcp://localhost:61616
-Dwebconsole.jmx.url= service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi
```

That should pretty much be it. You don't even need the console in the same JVM or machine as your broker.

Comment: Firstly: THANKS!! That is really interesting..surfing on web  is always said that the console is incorporated in activemq! so it's ANOTHER war...wow.. but still didn't get this part "by building activemq-web-console with maven", is there a pom for that? 
Tomorrow anyway i'll add some more info in my question, you're right it's too vague, but i can explain every part u need!

Comment: ActiveMQ has an embedded jetty container that holds a few web-apps, in exploded form. Look at conf/jetty.xml for config.

Never mind, I updated the answer with a link to the released .war file for the console. You can find it in some global maven repos.